# Missing loads of tabs on active directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019

I was working inside of AD UC and all of a sudden, loads of tabs from the properties menu have disappeared for everything, OU's etc.. Now these are the only options:

[image]

Even with advanced mode I still don't get 'Members' tab.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've right-clicked and selected the properties of an Organizational Unit (OU, or a "folder" in ADUC). What you're expecting to see would be found when you view the properties of an Object (a user or computer or group object that is stored INSIDE an OU).

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "View" menu and check "Advanced Features", all the tabs will be displayed again

[image: View-Advanced Features]